# Removing special characters from a column value in a find_by query in Ruby on Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my database i have a column named 'personal_id' which stores a unique value for each user. The thing is this value sometimes has special characters such as dots or lines ('.', '-'). I don't want to "normalize" my database to store the value without special characters, but i would like to find a specific user with a personal_id, removing all special characters from both the input value and the stored value.

For this, I am using `find_by`, so I've been trying to do something like: `User.find_by("replace(personal_id, '-', '.', ' ') = ?", 'replace(input, '-', '.', ' ')')`. This is supposed to remove special characters from stored value and input value, and find the user that matches the search, but it is clearly not working and i can't seem to find the solution to my problem. The output i get with this is `No function matches the name and argument types...`

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: The quick and dirty way to do this is to add a searchable_id column, and add a trigger that populates this when a record is added or updated. As part of that migration or a folllow on, update the new column for existing rows.

Comment: Thank you both for trying to help. I actually managed to do what i wanted with: `User.find_by("REGEXP_REPLACE(personal_id, '[^A-Za-z0-9]', '', 'g') = ?", personal_id)`. As i understand, this works like `.gsub` in Ruby. What it does is remove everything that is not A-Z, a-z, or 0-9 from the stored value in database, and use that string for comparison.